# lazyloading with animation in listview workes not properlly.. the animation repeates itself automatically

Tags: android

public class LazyImageLoadAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        OnClickListener {

```
private int mCount = 1;

private Activity activity;

TransparentProgressDialog pdialog;

private ArrayList<Listdata> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

private int lastPosition;

String userid;
String login;

String favorrite = "0";

public LazyImageLoadAdapter(Activity a) {

    activity = a;

}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lastPosition = -1;
}

public LazyImageLoadAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Listdata> d,
        String loginn, String uid) {

    activity = a;
    data = d;

    login = loginn;

    userid = uid;

    pdialog = new TransparentProgressDialog(activity, R.drawable.loader);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

}

public void addMoreItems(int count) {

    mCount += count;

    if (mCount >= data.size()) {

        mCount = data.size();

    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getCount() {

    return mCount;

}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView title;
    public TextView textarea;
    public TextView textWide;
    public ImageView image;
    public RelativeLayout heart;
    public TextView textviewcond;
    public TextView textrupee;
    public LinearLayout layoutcontact;
    public LinearLayout layoutchat;
    public ImageView heartt;
    public ImageView hearttiner;
    public LinearLayout propertylayout;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    final Listdata tempValues = (Listdata) data.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchingdata, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewtitle);
        holder.textarea = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewarea);
        holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.heartt = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewheart);
        holder.hearttiner = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewheartiner);

        holder.textviewcond = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewcondition);
        holder.textrupee = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewrupees);

        holder.heart = (RelativeLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.heartlayout);
        holder.layoutcontact = (LinearLayout) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.layoutcontact);
        holder.layoutchat = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.layoutchat);

        holder.propertylayout = (LinearLayout) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.propertylayout);

        vi.setTag(holder);

    } else

        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity,
            (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
                    : R.anim.down_from_top);
    vi.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;


    holder.title.setText(tempValues.getcity());

    String areaa = tempValues.getarea_sq_ft();
```

the animation on list cell repeats itself continuously when there is one data item in listview.  i think the issue is regarding its position or arraylist size.  but i can't find the proper solution for it.

the listview cell moving automatically.  any solution for it?

for animation i use this
http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Implementing-Google-Plus-Style-ListView-Animations-on-Android

Comment: There are libs like picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) that handle this kinda of lazy loading quite good. Give it a try.

Comment: i think the getview method recall itself automatically...   any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors when implementing the BaseAdapter :

1. `public int getCount()` should return the size of the data you have so usually `return data.size()`.
2. `addMoreItems` is not adding any items is just incrementing the artificial size of your adapter. You should here do `data.add(aItem)`; then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to tell the adapter that the data array has indee change.
3. `public Object getItem(int position)` should return what the data is
   holding at that position, so usually `data.get(position);`
4. I don't really understand why are you overwritting the `notifyDataSetChanged()` and i think here is were your problem comes from.

Try to change thoses things and see how it goes. If you still have problems provide the full implementation of your adapter (it's trunkated).